# file copy using c in debian linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

can anybody show me

wat's wrong with my code .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
  FILE *fp1,*fp2;
  char ch,ch1;
  fp1=fopen("ma.dat","r");
  fp2=fopen("na.dat","w");
   while(!feof(fp1))
    {
      ch=fgetc(fp1);
      fprintf(fp2,"%c ",ch);
    }    
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

}
```

i 'm trying to read from a file and writing to another file. 
some problem exist .

thank's in advance

Comment: _some problem exist_ what problem exists?

Comment: What is *`"some problem exist"`* ? and avoid using feof() read [`while( !feof( file ) ) is always wrong`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: You should check for eof immediately after a character read.

Comment: Instead of using fprintf(), use fputc().

Comment: I'm not sure about *anybody*, but I'm fairly confident `gdb` and/or some instrumented `printf()`s would be pretty telling. You're on Debian, so `gdb` is there.

Comment: problem : file to be written cannot be opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your while loop -

```
while(1) // or TRUE or for(;;)
{
  ch=fgetc(fp1);
  // or if (fp1 == -1)
  if (feof(fp1)) { // you're printing eof to fp2... not a good idea.
    break;
  }
  fprintf(fp2, "%c", ch); // or fputc(ch, fp2); your string format included a space!
}
```

or the shorter (and idiomatic) -

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) 
  fputc(ch. fp2);
```

Or your could use the linux specific,

```
fseek(fp1, 0L, SEEK_END);
long sz = ftell(fp1);
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
sendfile(fp2, fp1, 0, sz);
```

Comment: while(true) 

'true' cause following error


fcp.c: In function ‘main’:
fcp.c:10: error: ‘true’ undeclared (first use in this function)
fcp.c:10: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
fcp.c:10: error: for each function it appears in.)

Comment: @user1 sorry. TRUE or 1.

Comment: while(1) works successfully. Thankyou very much for your valuable help.

Comment: This code works, but the idiomatic way is **while ((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) fputc(ch. fp2);**

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Updated. And I added the even more idiomatic (and linux specific) sendfile call.